# Is there a unified form for Process control and process control analysis

Tags: quality-control

I have done some reading (NIST, JMP, PCS, Juran, some JEDEC, ...) and it appears there are four very common general types of control charts:

- Shewhart (X-bar, R, S)
- CUSUM (cumulative sum)
- EWMA (exponentially weighted moving average)
- GMA (geometric moving average)

Questions:
Is there a generalized form that integrates these?  It would be something that for one set of parameters yields a Shewhart but with a change yields the CUSUM.  Does it exist?

Outside of particular cases, or general synthetic data, how are they compared?  Is there a way to compare them analytically?